# Do "chess engine in the cloud" services exist?

Tags: engines

And if so, what interfaces can connect to them, and how do they do that?

I want to analyze with Lc0, but I don't have a computer with a GPU; I could rent one for a short time period at various cloud providers, but then I don't know what GUI I could use to talk to an engine running somewhere on the Internet.

Do e.g. Chessbase, Scid, Aquarium etc have a feature to work with engines running in the cloud?

Comment: Google Colab offers free GPU access for tensorflow applications if you can get an engine to run on it, that could be an option

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chessbase has this feature for subscribers. Basically you can analyse your games using their cloud based engine. If you have a powerful machine yourself you can also "rent out" your engine. More details [here](https://en.chessbase.com/post/tutorial-how-does-the-engine-cloud-work).

Here is an [older article](https://en.chessbase.com/post/chessbase-account-using-cloud-engines) which includes a video explaining how it works and walks you through the process.

Answer (score 8):

[Next Chess Move](https://nextchessmove.com/) offers a number of engines in the cloud including LC0, although they charge a subscription fee for access to more powerful hardware.

At the time of writing, they provide an app on Android and iOS, though it doesn't appear to have any integration with desktop programs.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for cloud engines that can be used outside of ChessBase as well, I'd highly recommend taking a quick view at the services offered by Chessify. Alongside other engines, we offer a 100kN/s GPU server for Leela Chess Zero at a rate of $0.10 per minute. You can use our service on ChessBase, SCID, or directly on our website.

Check out the full list of our servers/engines and prices [here](https://chessify.me/#cloud_content). We provide up to 500,000kN/s cloud servers for different chess engines. I'll be happy to answer any related questions. You can also contact me at ani@chessify.me.

Comment: Ani, as of 10/3/2020, I can't find anything on your site about using your cloud engine either (a) with Scid (or any GUI other than ChessBase) or (b) directly from the website (e.g., entering a FEN for a position to be analyzed). Please give more specifics, since it's not currently obvious from your website.

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for writing to me. If you want to use the engines directly on our website, you should create an account from here: https://chessify.me/pro. You can access this page by clicking on "cloud pro" from the top right corner of our main webpage.
If you want to download the plugin for ChessBase, please scroll all the way down on https://chessify.me/ and you'll see the corresponding button. Let me know if this helps. I'll gladly help with further questions.